# How to contribute an embed to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

[enter image description here][1]

There are many embed options in the WordPress embeds area, how to add my website to show in this area too?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQFTj.png

Comment: ``<iframe src="https://www.ashokkumawat.com" title="></iframe>``
you can use iframe for it

Comment: Please do not just ignore prompts like *enter image description here*.

Comment: Yes, we already use an iframe and users can embed our content on WordPress. However, I am asking about how to make our brand show on the editor's panel like Youtube, Facebook, and more. So, the users can choose the brand and paste the link.